# jQuery Mobile - loading message threshold

Tags: jquery-mobile

I was wondering if there is a way to extend the time it takes jQuery to display the "Loading" message when navigating from one page to the next.  Right now, it seems that if a page loads faster than approx. 100ms, the message doesn't appear.  If it is longer than that, the message shows up until the page is loaded.

Is there a way to increase this threshold from 100ms (or whatever it actually is) to let's say 500ms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by setting `$.mobile.loadPage.defaults.loadMsgDelay = 500` preferably in the `mobileinit` event handler.

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.loadPage.defaults.loadMsgDelay = 500
});
```

What this code will do is,if the page can be loaded within 500ms, loading message will not be shown.

**Edit** - This script has to be loaded after you load jquery but before you load jquery mobile.Please refer http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Comment: for some reason, it didn't work with 

$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){...

But I was successful to get it to work with 

$('[data-role=page]').live("pageshow", function() {...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to be of help.Ideally this has to be done in mobileinit.pageshow will be triggered when all the pages are shown and loadMsgDelay  will be set whenever a page is shown.Actually this is not needed and the value need to be set only once.See if my edit has solved the problem.